# creating and using Strings with surrogate pairs

Tags: java, string, unicode

I have to work with codepoints above `0FFFF` (specifically math scripted characters) and have not found simple tutorials on how to do this. I want to be able to (a) create `String`s with high codepoints and (b) iterate over the characters in them. Since `char` cannot hold these points my code looks like:

```
    @Test
public void testSurrogates() throws IOException {
    // creating a string
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("a");
    sb.appendCodePoint(120030);
    sb.append("b");
    String s = sb.toString();
    System.out.println("s> "+s+" "+s.length());
    // iterating over string
    int codePointCount = s.codePointCount(0, s.length());
    Assert.assertEquals(3, codePointCount);
    int charIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < codePointCount; i++) {
        int codepoint = s.codePointAt(charIndex);
        int charCount = Character.charCount(codepoint);
        System.out.println(codepoint+" "+charCount);
        charIndex += charCount;
    }
}
```

I don't feel comfortable that this is either fully correct or the cleanest way to do this. I would have expected methods such as `codePointAfter()` but there is only a `codePointBefore()`. Please confirm that this is the right strategy or give an alternate one.

UPDATE: Thanks for the confirmation @Jon. I struggled with this - here are two mistakes to avoid:

- there is no direct index into the code points (i.e. no `s.getCodePoint(i))` - you have to iterate through them
- using `(char)` as a cast will truncate integers above `0FFFF` and it's not easy to spot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks correct to me. If you want to iterate over the code points in a string, you could wrap this code in an `Iterable`:

```
public static Iterable<Integer> getCodePoints(final String text) {
    return new Iterable<Integer>() {
        @Override public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
            return new Iterator<Integer>() {
                private int nextIndex = 0;

                @Override public boolean hasNext() {
                    return nextIndex < text.length();
                }

                @Override public Integer next() {
                    if (!hasNext()) {
                        throw new NoSuchElementException();
                    }
                    int codePoint = text.codePointAt(nextIndex);
                    nextIndex += Character.charCount(codePoint);
                    return codePoint;
                }

                @Override public void remove() {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

Or you could change the method to just return an `int[]` of course:

```
public static int[] getCodePoints(String text) {
    int[] ret = new int[text.codePointCount(0, text.length())];
    int charIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) {
        ret[i] = text.codePointAt(charIndex);
        charIndex += Character.charCount(ret[i]);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I agree that it's a pity that the Java libraries don't expose methods like this already, but at least they're not *too* hard to write.